# Java - Returning constructor method with array

Tags: java, arrays

I have 2 files, one of which request user input, and one of which returns array values based on user input. I'm having an issue returning my array. I'm only receiving specific elements within each array, although I'd like to return the whole thing. Do you see what I'm missing? Thanks.

```
  // Filename SalonReport.java

  import java.util.*;
  import javax.swing.*;
  import java.util.Scanner;
  import java.util.Arrays;

  public class SalonReport {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  int x, y, sortSelect, view;
  boolean repeat = false;
  boolean loop = false;
  int z = 1;


  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

  System.out.print("Welcome to Erik's Hair Salon");
  System.out.println();

  //Using do-while to assign selection
  do
     if(z > 0)
     {
  //Welcoming message
        Service description = new Service();
        Service price = new Service();
        Service minutes = new Service();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("We offer the following services at our salon:");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Service" + "\t" + "\t" + "Price" + "\t"  + "Minutes");
        System.out.println("************************************");
           for (x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
              for (y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
                 System.out.print(description.getService() + "\t" + "\t");
              }
              System.out.println();
           }

  //User input message

        System.out.println("How do you wish to sort our table of services?");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("To sort by Service Description, enter 1 >>");
        System.out.println("To sort by Price, enter 2 >>");
        System.out.println("To sort by Minutes, enter 3 >>");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("To exit, enter 0 >> ");
           sortSelect = input.nextInt();

           if(sortSelect == 1)
           {
           System.out.println();
           System.out.println("Service" + "\t" + "\t" + "Price" + "\t"  + "Minutes");
           System.out.println("************************************");
           for (x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
              for (y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
                 System.out.print(description.getService() + "\t" + "\t");
                 }
              System.out.println();
              repeat = true;
              }
           }
           else if(sortSelect == 2)
           {
           System.out.println();
           System.out.println("Price" + "\t" + "\t" + "Service" + "\t"  + "Minutes");
           System.out.println("************************************");
              for (x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
                 for (y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
                    System.out.print(price.getPrice() + "\t" + "\t");
                 }
              System.out.println();
              repeat = true;
              }
           }
           else if(sortSelect == 3)
           {
           System.out.println();
           System.out.println("Minutes" + "\t" + "\t" + "Service" + "\t"  + "Price");
           System.out.println("************************************");
              for (x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
                 for (y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
                    System.out.print(minutes.getTime() + "\t" + "\t");
                 }
              System.out.println();
              repeat = true;
              }
           }
           else if(sortSelect == 0)
                    {
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                    break;
                    }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Do you wish to view our services again?");
        System.out.println("Enter 1 for Yes >>");
        System.out.print("Enter 0 for No >> ");
           view = input.nextInt();
              if(view == 1)
                 {
                 loop = true;
                 repeat = true;
                 }
                 else if(view == 0)
                    {
                    loop = false;
                    repeat = false;
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                    break;
                    }
        }
        else
           {
           repeat = false;
           System.out.println();
           System.out.println("Goodbye!");
              break;
           }
     while(repeat = true);
  }
  }


  // Filename Service.java

  import java.util.*;
  import javax.swing.*;
  import java.util.Scanner;


  public class Service {

  private String[][] sortByDesc = {{"Cut", "$8.00", "15"}, {"Mani.", "$18.00", "30"}, {"Perm.",       
  "$18.00", "35"}, {"Shampoo", "$4.00", "10"}, {"Style", "$48.00", "55"}, {"Trim", "$6.00",       
  "5"}};
  private String[][] sortByPrice = {{"$4.00", "Shampoo", "10"}, {"$6.00", "Trim", "5"}, 
  {"$8.00", "Cut", "15"}, {"$18.00", "Mani.", "30"}, {"$18.00","Perm", "35"}, {"$48.00", 
  "Style", "55"}};
  private String[][] sortByTime = {{"5", "Trim", "$6.00"}, {"10", "Shampoo", "$4.00"}, {"15",       
  "Cut", "$8.00"}, {"30", "Mani.", "$18.00"}, {"35","Perm", "$18.00"}, {"55", "Style", 
  "$48.00"}};



   public String getService() {
       return sortByDesc[5][2];
   }

   public String getPrice() {
       return sortByPrice[5][2];
   }

   public String getTime() {
       return sortByTime[5][2];
   }
  }
```

Comment: The get methods in Service do not look right to me. Why are they like that?

Comment: learn to properly indent your code, and learn to leave meaningful pieces in question, please.

Comment: @AdrianShum according to this, my code is properly indented: http://www.javaranch.com/styleLong.jsp#indent

Comment: @trappist This isnt java ranch, and you SalonReport is not formatted at all

Comment: @trappist I cannot see how your code is "properly indented" even base on your quoted article.  Do you need me to point out line by line where indentation is wrong?  Almost every possible problem of indentation, you got that in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   public String getService() {
       return sortByDesc[5][2];
   }
```

does only return the element on position 5/2. If you want to return the whole Array it should be like

```
    public String [][] getService() {
       return sortByDesc;
   }
```

Comment: This is working, somewhat... for every element now I'm receiving the following: [[Ljava.lang.String;@55991e21

Comment: `toString()` of arrays is not working as you expect. Manually print the content out and you will find it is working fine

Comment: @trappist e.g. within your "welcome message" write `System.out.print(description.getService()[x][y] + "\t" + "\t");` instead of just `System.out.print(description.getService() + "\t" + "\t");`